# SoapUI - GET Method need to show range of IDs

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

I am creating a Test Project in SoapUI to test our API Gateway and need to do the following things for reporting automation:

I have an example JSON file :

```
 {
    "id": 1111111,
    "name": "name",
    "created_at": "create_at",
    "updated_at": "updated_at",
    "attributes": [{
        WHOLE ATTRIBIUTES
    }],
    "tags": [],
    "company_id": "A123"
 }
```

I want to do a few things :

- Show only the data filtered by company_id in range fo ex. from A123 to A321 in header and save that to some csv or txt file by file:result.txt
- Define the value for range as A$Num form X to Y.

I was searching for a couple solutions with Groovy script with no success. Any ideas? Should I focus on filtering by header or path what is also available?

I tried using `JsonSlurper`, like:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent 
def slurper = new JsonSlurper() 
def json = slurper.parseText response 
assert json.company_id = ("K",123 > 321)
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO ! I don't see a code in your question - can you post the code if you've tried out any ? Also have a read on - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I trying to use JsonSlurper something like this:

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def json = slurper.parseText response
assert json.Token.company_id = ("K",123 > 321)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things can help you:

- regular expression for extracting int value part from your full `company_id`. Using regexp instead of simple string manipulation is just more maintainable, readable and more versatile. Anyway, you always may use `String.substring()` to extract that int val.
- groovy ranges and `in` operator for checking if id is in range.

I suppose that you've collected all responses as strings in `allResponses` list, here's how filtering and writing all jsons to file would look like:

```
def companyIdPattern = ~/A(\d+)/
def companyIdRange = 100..500 // X..Y inclusively, X..<Y - for exclusive Y
def resultFile = new File('result.txt')
def parser = new JsonSlurper()
allResponses.collect { parser.parseText(it) }
        .findAll {
            // match company_id text to regexp and extract int value part
            def idVal = (it.company_id =~ companyIdPattern)[0][1]?.toInteger()
            idVal in companyIdRange
        }.each {
            // there could be any pre-processing needed to write result (convert json to csv, etc.)
            resultFile << it.toString()
        }
```